# s:SpriteVisualElement and "component declarations are not allowed here"

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Take a look at the following code.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:view="client.view.*" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:Panel x="10" y="10" height="100%" title="CTW" borderColor="#008040" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="13">
        <s:HGroup>
            ...
            <s:Scroller id="canvasGroup" width="650" height="500">
                <s:Group>
                    <s:SpriteVisualElement>
                        <view:PNGCanvas id="canvas" />  <!-- error is thrown here -->
                    </s:SpriteVisualElement>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Scroller>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:Panel>  
</s:Application>
```

`PNGCanvas` extends `flash.display.Sprite`. I'm getting an error `component declarations are not allowed here` (on line marked with `error is thrown here`). What's wrong here?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: `s:SpriteVisualElement` is not a container class so that's why `component declarations are not allowed here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be like this...

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:view="view.*"> 
    <s:Panel x="10" y="10" height="100%" title="CTW" borderColor="#008040" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="13"> 
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Scroller id="canvasGroup" width="650" height="500"> 
                <s:Group> 
                    <view:PNGCanvas width="100" height="100"/> 
                </s:Group> 
            </s:Scroller> 
        </s:HGroup> 
    </s:Panel>   
</s:Application>
```

and PNGCanvas class should be extend by SpriteVisualElement

```
package view
{   
    import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

    public class PNGCanvas extends SpriteVisualElement
    {
        public function PNGCanvas()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

check this code...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure A SpriteVisualelement can't have children (in MXML) as it is not a container.

You could change PNGCanvas to extend Canvas; then use that instead of your SpriteVisualElement.

Additionally you could add your PNGCanvas instance as a child to your SpriteVisualElement using ActionScript; but it is slightly more complex.

Answer (score 0):

your code may not be working due to this...

The SpriteVisualElement class is a light-weight Sprite-based implemention of the IVisualElement interface. Spark containers can lay out and render SpriteVisualElement objects. 
If you use ActionScript to add an FXG component to an application, it should be of type SpriteVisualElement.